# Coerce Eff or Aff to a satisfy a function expecting a larger set of effects

Tags: purescript

I have an effectful asynchronous action with a type, let's say,

```
effectful :: Aff e r
```

I would like to build an action that takes some asynchronous action and sends the result to a `Channel` from [purescript-signal](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-signal/). The `send` function has the signature:

```
send :: forall a e. Channel a -> a -> Eff (channel :: CHANNEL | e) Unit
```

Here is the implementation I came up with:

```
runAffToChannel :: forall a e. Channel a
                -> Aff e a
                -> Eff (channel :: CHANNEL | e) Unit
runAffToChannel chan = runAff_ $ either ignore $ send chan
  where
    ignore = const (pure unit)
```

The types do not unify here between `e` and `channel :: CHANNEL | e`.

How do I convert the value of type `Aff e a` to `Aff (channel :: CHANNEL | e) a`, or at least `Eff e a` to `Eff (channel :: CHANNEL | e) a`?

Answer (score 2):

When using effect rows, it's generally best to use the same row everywhere even if the effects aren't "required" in every place. So in this case, the type for the `Aff` argument should include `channel` too:

```
runAffToChannel :: forall a e. Channel a
                -> Aff (channel :: CHANNEL | e) a
                -> Eff (channel :: CHANNEL | e) Unit
```

Using effect rows like this might seem not quite right (and is a little unfortunate, as it makes the rows "wider" than they need to be in some places), but it saves a lot of pain in making the rows all line up.